# How to SELECT FROM stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns rows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
END
```

My actual procedure is a little more complicated, which is why a stored procedure is necessary.

Is it possible to select the output by calling this procedure?

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (EXEC MyProc) AS TEMP
```

I need to use `SELECT TOP X`, `ROW_NUMBER`, and an additional `WHERE` clause to page my data, and I don't really want to pass these values as parameters.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you intend to do here because when you execute the procedure, you are getting the rows back. Is it that you want to execute the procedure inside a SELECT statement so you can tie it to a pageable object?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to pass the values as parameters? To do it the way you are suggesting is a bit inefficent - you would be selecting more data than you need, and then not using it all.

Comment: Take a look at here: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: If anyone wants to insert the sp output into a TABLE variable have a lot of columns in your sp, press `Ctrl+T` to output the result as text, and copy the first column line and remove extra whitespaces from there and you'll get your column names easily. To go back to Grid output press `Ctrl+D`

Comment: **Beware all ye who enter here:** There are only about three answers provided below atm: **1.** use a function (accepted answer), **2.** use a table variable or temp table and `INSERT` the `EXEC` [***iff*** your sproc isn't too complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411#comment24260611_1492432), **3.** [cheat and use `OPENQUERY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1492502/1028230). But each answer is repeated an amazing number of times, many with a downright startling number of upvotes. You've been warned. 

Comment: @ruffin naturally I found out the truth of which you speak the hard way before finally finding your comment.

Comment: I've added the answer I came here looking for, enticed by the title, even if it's not exactly what the conditions of the OP required (needing to use TOP, WHERE, etc.)  
In summary: `MyProcedure 'Hello', 1`

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use a [User-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions) or a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views) instead of a procedure.

A procedure can return multiple result sets, each with its own schema. It's not suitable for using in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Additionally, if after converting to a UDF you find you need the stored procedure semantics you can always wrap the UDF with a procedure.

Comment: what if, we need to send parameters to mulple stored procedures and combine them into one one big stored procedure? Can view, take parameters, like stored procedures does

Comment: @mrN Views don't take parameters, but UDFs do.

Comment: Hello, I really need to do this without converting the sp to a view or function, is it possible?

Comment: @LuisBecerril Same here. The underlying sproc is protected and I have no permission to change it (or even view the script)

Comment: While your answer is a true statement it doesn't answer the question.... "SELECT FROM stored procedure" Which sure it's not ideal, but it is what it is...

@Aamir's answer is the correct answer. Either that or the question needs to be changed... which seems a bit ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 293):

You can

1. create a table variable to hold the
   result set from the stored proc and
   then
2. insert the output of the
       stored proc into the table variable,
       and then
3. use the table variable
           exactly as you would any other
           table...

... sql ....

```
Declare @T Table ([column definitions here])
Insert @T Exec storedProcname params 
Select * from @T Where ...
```

Comment: The problem with `INSERT #T` or `INSERT @T` is that an `INSERT EXEC` statement cannot be nested.
If the stored procedure already has an `INSERT EXEC` in it, this won't work.

Comment: This probably the most portable solution, being closest to basic SQL.  It also helps to maintain strong column type definitions. Should have more upvotes than those above.

Comment: The [table variables](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/) looks more useful here than temporary tables in terms of sp recompile. So I agree, this answer should have more upvotes.

Answer (score 96):

You either want a [Table-Valued function](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/intro-to-user-defined-functions-updated) or insert your EXEC into a temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO #tab EXEC MyProc
```

Comment: The problem with `INSERT #T` or `INSERT @T` is that an `INSERT EXEC` statement cannot be nested.
If the stored procedure already has an `INSERT EXEC` in it, this won't work.

Answer (score 75):

You need to declare a table type which contains the same number of columns your store procedure is returning. Data types of the columns in the table type and the columns returned by the procedures should be same

```
declare @MyTableType as table
(
FIRSTCOLUMN int
,.....
)
```

Then you need to insert the result of your stored procedure in your table type you just defined

```
Insert into @MyTableType 
EXEC [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
```

In the end just select from your table type

```
Select * from @MyTableType
```

Comment: That is the best solution for me, because you don't need to specify the server name, connection strings or have to configure any linked servers in order to make it work - which are things I don't want to do to just to get some data back. Thank you! Awsome answer!

Comment: When stored procedure is too dificult - this method not workin, for example, when stored procedure use two temp-tables.

Comment: It works only inside stored procedure. In query console (as a separate query) it causes an error: "An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.".

Comment: This is same answer as mine above... except (admittedly, picking at nits here) , that this is ***not*** creating a new table *type*, it is declaring a new table *variable*

Answer (score 56):

You must read about [**OPENROWSET**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [**OPENQUERY**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT  * 
INTO    #tmp FROM    
OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC MyProc @parameters')
```

Comment: How to get YOURSERVERNAME dynamically? You can't expect to have to know always. Won't this break every other Tuesday? So If I've got 100 servers all with different names...

Comment: also what if my database is not configured to allow this?

Comment: Try @@servername to get it dynamically

Answer (score 38):

It is not necessary use a temporary table.

This is my solution

```
SELECT  *  FROM    
OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC MyProc @parameters')
WHERE somefield = anyvalue
```

Comment: This needs you to add your server as a linked server to itself, but it works like a charm! thanks!

Comment: Some great caveats on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374741/why-is-using-openquery-on-a-local-server-bad

Comment: Hmm ... I am getting the error "Error 7411: Server 'YourServerName' is not configured for DATA ACCESS." What do I need to change?

Comment: Have you add your server as a linked server? YourServerName is the name  of your server. You have to change YourServerName with your real server name.

Comment: @Matt: `sp_serveroption 'MYSERVER', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE;`

Comment: @alexkovelsky - Thanks, calling `EXEC sp_serveroption 'MYSERVER', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE;` indeed makes the error disappear. But now I am getting a syntax error when I execute `SELECT  *  FROM    
OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC MyProc @parameters')` - even a pass-through query like `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (Server, 'SELECT name FROM dbo.Customers`);` as mentioned [here in Section D.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) gives me a syntax error. What else is missing?

Comment: @vaheeds `You cannot create a local SQL Server as a linked server` How to get past that error ?

Answer (score 30):

You can copy output from sp to temporaty table.

```
CREATE TABLE #GetVersionValues
(
    [Index] int,
    [Name]  sysname,
    Internal_value  int,
    Character_Value sysname
)
INSERT #GetVersionValues EXEC master.dbo.xp_msver 'WindowsVersion'
SELECT * FROM #GetVersionValues
drop TABLE #GetVersionValues
```

Answer (score 8):

Try converting your procedure in to an Inline Function which returns a table as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyProc()
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (SELECT * FROM MyTable)
```

And then you can call it as

```
SELECT * FROM MyProc()
```

You also have the option of passing parameters to the function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FuncName (@para1 para1_type, @para2 para2_type , ... )
```

And call it

```
SELECT * FROM FuncName ( @para1 , @para2 )
```

Answer (score 8):

If 'DATA ACCESS' false,

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'SQLSERVERNAME', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE
```

after,

```
SELECT  *  FROM OPENQUERY(SQLSERVERNAME, 'EXEC DBNAME..MyProc @parameters')
```

it works.

Answer (score 7):

You can cheat a little with OPENROWSET :

```
SELECT ...fieldlist...
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'connection string', 'name of sp')
WHERE ...
```

This would still run the entire SP every time, of course.

Comment: SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' in SQL Server Books Online.

Answer (score 7):

Use OPENQUERY, and before execute set `SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON;`

Try this sample code:

```
SELECT top(1)*
FROM
OPENQUERY( [Server], 'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXECUTE  [database].[dbo].[storedprocedure]  value,value ')
```

If you get the error 'Server is not configured for DATA ACCESS',
use this:

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'YourServer', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of simplicity and to make it re-runnable, I have used a system StoredProcedure "sp_readerrorlog" to get data:

```
-----USING Table Variable
DECLARE @tblVar TABLE (
   LogDate DATETIME,
   ProcessInfo NVARCHAR(MAX),
   [Text] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @tblVar Exec sp_readerrorlog
SELECT LogDate as DateOccured, ProcessInfo as pInfo, [Text] as Message FROM @tblVar



-----(OR): Using Temp Table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #temp;
CREATE TABLE #temp (
   LogDate DATETIME,
   ProcessInfo NVARCHAR(55),
   Text NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #temp EXEC sp_readerrorlog
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might just need to use a [view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258253%28SQL.80%29.aspx).  A view allows a query to be represented as a table so it, the view, can be queried.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is called SERVERX for example, this is how I did it...

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'SERVERX', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE;
DECLARE @CMD VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @StudentID CHAR(10);
SET @StudentID = 'STUDENT01';
SET @CMD = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([SERVERX], ''SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXECUTE MYDATABASE.dbo.MYSTOREDPROC ' + @StudentID + ''') WHERE SOMEFIELD = SOMEVALUE';
EXEC (@CMD);
```

To check this worked, I commented out the `EXEC()` command line and replaced it with `SELECT @CMD` to review the command before trying to execute it! That was to make sure all the correct number of single-quotes were in the right place.  :-)

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I find this usefull.
Real example.

```
declare @tempv1 table (Number int, AccountType varchar(255), DisplayName varchar(255), Kind int, UsagePageBreak int, PrimoPrev money, PrevPeriod money, UltimoPrev money, Primo money, Debit money, Credit money, Period money, Ultimo money, ToCurrentDate money, IndexUltimoPct money, IndexPeriodPct money, UltimoPrevOK int, UltimoOK int)
declare @tempv2 table (Number int, AccountType varchar(255), DisplayName varchar(255), Kind int, UsagePageBreak int, PrimoPrev money, PrevPeriod money, UltimoPrev money, Primo money, Debit money, Credit money, Period money, Ultimo money, ToCurrentDate money, IndexUltimoPct money, IndexPeriodPct money, UltimoPrevOK int, UltimoOK int)


insert into @tempv1

exec  sp_reports_Accounting_BalanceV2 
@fromaccount=1010,
@toaccount=1010,
@fromfinancialdate = '2021-01-01 00:00:00 +01:00', 
@tofinancialdate = '2021-12-31 00:00:00+01:00', 
@includezero=0,@ouids=NULL,@currentOrganizationalUnitId=1,@currentuserid=1,@includenotbooked=0


insert into @tempv2

exec sp_reports_Accounting_BalanceV3
@fromaccount=1010,
@toaccount=1010,
@fromfinancialdate = '2021-01-01 00:00:00 +01:00', 
@tofinancialdate = '2021-12-31 00:00:00+01:00', 
@includezero=0,@ouids=NULL,@currentOrganizationalUnitId=1,@currentuserid=1,@includenotbooked=0


select * from @tempv1 except select * from @tempv2
union all
select * from @tempv2 except select * from @tempv1
```

Answer (score -3):

Several hours and 131 google searches later, turns out all I really needed was:

```
MyProcedure -- this is so simple it doesn't look like an executable line of code so here's a comment to make it look more substantial
```

(no EXEC, no SELECT, no brackets...)

**Hit F5 / Run** - and you shall have your table of results.

So, to clarify: just put the procedure name - if you need to put in parameters, put a space and then the parameters you wish to pass in, separated by a comma if you have multiple.

**Example with parameters:**

```
MyProcedure 'Hello', 1
```

(Single quotations needed for varchar; no quotes for bit and integer.)