# Stored procedure as CTE_query_definition

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

Can I use a stored procedure as the `CTE_query_definition` of a CTE?

For example:

```
WITH  CodesCTE
AS ( Exec sp_TableReturningProc )
SELECT * FROM CodesCTE;
```

If not, outside of declaring a batch / global temp table and using a `Select` statement against the temp table, is there a way around this limitation?

I am in the process of developing the associated stored procedure and would love to simply the use of it for this purpose if possible.

Comment: No. Some possible workarounds here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Comment: So its going to be a Temp Table design.  Oh Well, guess ill be implementing Resource Management as well ;)