# How can I use a select statement in conjuction with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

How can I achieve something like this :

```
SELECT * DISTINCT FROM 
(execute dbo.MyStoredProcedure(@ID1,@ID2))
```

suppose that's inside another stored procedure.

How can I call a stored procedure from another stored procedure and get the result as a table
(my select is intended for that)

Comment: have you considered searching? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
DECLARE @TableTemp TABLE (--declare parameters, ouput from SP)

INSERT INTO @TableTemp
EXEC dbo.MyStoredProcedure @ID1,@ID2

SELECT * FROM @TableTemp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
INSERT INTO #temp 
EXEC MyStoredProcedure(@ID1,@ID2)

SELECT * FROM #temp
```