# SELECT from stored procedure inside a view

Tags: sql-server

Can someone enlighten me as to why this will not work?

I have a stored procedure that returns a table:
calling it like so works fine:

```
EXECUTE dbo.sp_Get_Total_Parcels_Paid_Data
```

However, I need to use this inside of a view, and cannot get it to work.

```
Select * from dbo.sp_Get_Total_Parcels_Paid_Data()
```

Error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.sp_Get_Total_Parcels_Paid_Data()

SP Code:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Get_Total_Parcels_Paid_Data]
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Sql1 nvarchar(max)
,@Sql2 nvarchar(max)
,@Sql3 nvarchar(max)

declare @TallyResults table
(EFOLDERID nvarchar(31) null    
,inv_bank_cd int null
,inv_cd int null
,inv_group_cd int null
,intLoanNumber int null
,other_text nvarchar(250) null
,tallyCount int
,eidMgrId nvarchar(31))


select @Sql1 = 'Select ' + tallydefinition from jobfunctions where jobfuncid = 44
select @Sql2 = 'Select ' + tallydefinition from jobfunctions where jobfuncid = 45
select @Sql3 = 'Select ' + tallydefinition from jobfunctions where jobfuncid = 206

insert into @TallyResults exec sp_executesql @Sql1
insert into @TallyResults exec sp_executesql @Sql2
insert into @TallyResults exec sp_executesql @Sql3

select * from @TallyResults

END
```

Comment: this looks like something you could roll into a view without having to do the gnarly multiple select statements that insert into a table variable. this looks like an optimization nightmare. is `tallydefinition` a column? your dynamic sql in the stored procedure looks like it might throw an error.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s [I revisited those tests recently too](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Answer (score 5):

You can't `SELECT FROM <procedure>`, sorry. Maybe you can try [the `OPENQUERY` trick](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-temp-table-in-sql-server-that-can-hold-the-re), but I'm not sure you'll be able to put that in a view.

Answer (score 0):

We can't execute a Stored Procedure in a Select statement. Here's a similar thread

[SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) is what you want

Perhaps, this will guide you the ways in which you can get the result set from one SP to another.