# SQL getting the output from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, return, output

Just starting out with SQL, so there's probably a really easy answer here, but I couldn't figure out exactly what i needed to do from a google search.

There's a stored procedure in the database I'm using called dt_char_sp - simply put, the parameters are the date and time as ints, and the stored procedure formats them nicely. I would expect that it works something like this:

```
EXEC dt_char_sp 20130416, 024356
go
```

output:

```
04/06/2013 02:43:56
```

except the output doesn't happen! I see that there is a variable declared as "@datetime datetime=NULL OUTPUT" and eventually the @datetime variable is filled with the formatted string, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get this output variable?

Comment: There's not enough info here to provide assistance.  Are you calling this from code (.NET, Java, PHP)?  (And if so what language) or using a tool/software like SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot be sure without actually seeing the stored procedure, but it sounds like it is using an output parameter.

```
DECLARE @retval As DATETIME

EXEC dt_char_sp 20130416, 024356, @datetime=@retval OUTPUT

PRINT @retval
go
```

There is an equivalent way to do this from client code as well.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the OUTPUT keyword outside of the stored_proc, and that is why this wasn't working. end result was: `declare @datetime2 datetime exec dt_char_sp 20130401, 111111, @datetime=@datetime2 OUTPUT Select @datetime2;`

Comment: @user1642475 Yeah, everyone forgets about it at first.  It always seems unnatural/illogical that you have to specify it on *CALL*, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Select statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp).

At the end of your query just Select the desired output variable like so :

```
SELECT @datetime
```

Another way would be to use an [Output Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Declared like so :

```
@datetime DateTime OUTPUT;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working...
In the stored procedure, @datetime is initially defined as:

Comment: I will imply you are using Sql Server. Go in object explorer/YourDatabase/Programmability/StoredProcedure/ right click on dt_char_sp  and modify it. At the very end of the procedure last line add `SELECT @datetime` and run your query to apply changes. If it does not work give me the error

Comment: Ooooh got it. Is there a way to do this outside the stored procedure?

In the stored procedure @datetime is initially defined as:
`@datetime DateTime OUTPUT;`

Is there a way to reference this "OUTPUT" outside of the stroed proc? i.e. if I execute this in a separate SQL query?
something like:
`declare @datetime2 datetime
execute dt_char_sp 20130401, 111111, @datetime = @datetime2
select @datetime2`

Comment: What you're asking here is if you can [Select from a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure). Read this post it explains it way better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are doing something to get a return value?
If not, you can select the variable

```
select @datetime
```

Answer (score -1):

Please do not burden the SQL Server with lame stuff like formatting strings. It's much too important for that kind of thing. I see this a lot lately, and it's a bad habit.

Please, use your client formatting tools for this...

Something like (for UNIX-type dates)

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime("1/1/1970").AddDays(myIntDate);

Console.Writeln(dt.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"));
```

This is better for a lot of reasons - performance is the big one. You have all the data you need already, there is no reason to make a round-trip to a very expensive server when you don't really need anything from it. All computers can format dates, don't use the server for it.

This IS the correct answer by the way. I don't think Stack Overflow should become the place where if someone asks how to jump off a bridge, we just tell them. When someone is asking how to accomplish something USING THE WRONG METHOD, WE SHOULD TELL THEM THE CORRECT METHOD.

Comment: -1 this is clearly comment matter. Not even remotly answering the question

Comment: Hmm, good to know. Unfortunately in the broader context of what I'm trying to do switching the date in a shell script is not appropriate.

Comment: Then you should have said "I'm using a shell script and I need to have the server format strings for me" in your original question.