# Dynamically query a temp table created in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure that creates a temp table. Now I need to be able to query over it using .NET. So I would need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM storedProcedure() WHERE ...
```

The table created by the stored procedure is dynamic as well so the schema will change. Using SQL Server 2005.

I cant use a function because what needs to be returned is a dynamic table. Having to define the table beforehand makes a function useless.

I ended up creating a global temp table with the help of dynamic SQL I was able to create a dynamic global temp table and access it via .NET.

Comment: see this post:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Comment: Shall we assume SQL Server is your RDBMS? How about a global temp table?

Comment: @Bridge I was thinking about global temp table but would that not be overwritten if there are multiple transactions going on at the same time?

Comment: @Bridge I ended up using a global temp table as a function cant return a dynamic table it was no help. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As the reference indicates, you use something like:

```
insert into @t(<columns here>)
    exec stored_procedure;
```

However, in many cases, you can replace such a stored procedure with a user defined function.  These are defined to return values, and can be used exactly as you want to use it:

```
select *
from dbo.udf_MyFunction();
```

There are, of course, advantages and disadvantages to each approach.  One disadvantage to the stored procedure method is that you cannot nest such stored procedures.  One disadvantage to the function approach is that you cannot use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Using a function then is it possible to return a dynamic table because as I have seen with functions you must declare the returned table and its schema on creation?

Comment: @user1938919 . . . With an inline table valued function, the return clause specifies the format.  For a multi-line table valued function, then you need to declare the type as part of the definition.  However, to capture the stored procedure results in a table, you need to define the table *before* doing the insert, so you also need the table definition there.

Comment: Not going to work then I need to be able to create a dynamic table out of a JSON, join it with another table and then return that to be queried. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can select from stored procedure like this

```
select * 
from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=<your server here>;Database=<your database here>;Trusted_Connection=yes;','set fmtonly off exec <your procedure here>')
```

I, however, couldn't recommend doing this in production, think about changing your stored procedure to user defined function