# t-sql stored procedure add where clause outside of SP

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure that I cannot modify, but I need to add a where clause to filter it even more. What would be the best way to do this without inserting data from stored procedure to a temptable then doing a where on that temptable. Is there another way?

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

The store procedure is executable but filtering happens inside the select statement so you should bring the result in a table to select it.
There is no way except temp tables.
Table valued Udf also has table like temp tables.