# Order By from Stored Procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I have this stored procedure:

```
exec T2IntranetViaggi2SelezioneConMagazzinoCompetenza @Societa = 20, @Cliente = 55, @TipologiaData = 'P', @TipoData = 'S', @DataInizio = '2013-10-28 00:00:00', @DataFine = '2013-10-28 23:59:59', @DestinatarioCodice = null, @OrdineRiferimento = '', @RiferimentoInterno = '', @PassaggioTp = 'T', @UnitaMisura = '', @Esitato = 'T', @Consegnato = 'T', @CaricoLocalita = '', @CaricoCap = '', @CaricoProvincia = '', @CaricoNazione = '', @ScaricoLocalita = '', @ScaricoCap = '', @ScaricoProvincia = '', @ScaricoNazione = '', @MagazzinoCompetenza = '', @DocumentoNumero = ''
```

But I want to order the result by the "Documento" field.

I can't edit the stored procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the stored procedure doesn't, itself, use an [`INSERT`...`EXEC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx), then you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
    /* Columns as per the stored procedure's result set */
)

INSERT INTO #T (/* Column list */)
EXEC T2IntranetViaggi2SelezioneConMagazzinoCompetenza @Societa = 20, @Cliente = 55, ...

SELECT * FROM #T ORDER BY Documento
```

You also say that you cannot edit the stored procedure - if this is because there are other callers of this procedure, then one thing you might consider is duplicating the stored procedure as a user defined function (UDF), and then changing the stored procedure to just call the UDF.

You could then directly query the UDF yourself in a `SELECT` query and apply your desired ordering directly.

Of course, if the "cannot change" is for other reasons then this may not apply.

Comment: thanks Damien.... for the performance aspect is correct make a temp table on Sqlserver or order the array into PHP code?

Comment: @Antonio - I wouldn't expect PHP to be able to out-perform the SQL Server but whether there's any appreciable *difference* in the performance may depend on the exact structure of your data - number of rows and columns involved, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Store your sp's result in [table variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx), and then query to that table variable.

Example:

```
create proc p 
as
select code, name from customer
go
declare @t table
(
    code int,
    name varchar(30)
);
insert into @t
exec p;

select * from @t order by name desc;
```

Comment: The procedure I'm calling with EXEC itself contains a temporary table.  This method worked when many other things I tried didn't.  Thank you!