# How to get only Table Name using Sp_depends?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get table names alone used in Stored Procedure by `sp_depends`. 
For example

```
EXEC sp_depends Samplesp1
```

It gives table names and its column names used in `samplesp1`. But I need table names alone.

Comment: why not insert the result into a temp table and use just the table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is creating a Temporary table like sqluser have mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30588837/1155650) answer.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
 (NAME VARCHAR(250)
, [type] VARCHAR(250)
, updated CHAR(2)
, selected CHAR(3)
, [column] VARCHAR(250))

-- insert the data from procedure's rresult into temporary table
INSERT #temp
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'Samplesp1'

SELECT NAME
FROM #temp t
--Filter condition
WHERE t.type = 'user table'

drop TABLE #temp
```

This article- [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) shows various other methods suitable for your scenario.

Of all the options my personal favorite is using the `OPENQUERY`:

```
SELECT  *  FROM    
OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC MyProc @parameters')
WHERE somefield = anyvalue
```

There is an already well answered question in SO about the scenario - [SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure). Looking into the answers would give you some better options as well.

Comment: OPENQUERY solution doesn't seem to work in Azure SQL (12); 'OPENQUERY' rowset provider not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the result into a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    name VARCHAR(250)
    ,[type] VARCHAR(250)
    ,updated CHAR(2)
    ,selected CHAR(3)
    ,[column] VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT #tmp 
EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'yoursp'

SELECT name FROM #tmp
```

Comment: Plus one for answering while I was looking for the duplicate.

Comment: `sp_depends` has two recordsets, so this solution results in _Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Procedure sp_depends, Line 68 [Batch Start Line 0]
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition._. Not sure if this is a new feature of this proc and also not sure if the `openquery` solution fixes it