# How to retrieve dataset in RDLC report where one stored procedure return multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rdlc

I am creating a `.rdlc` report. There will be three table for show.

I've wrote a stored procedure Like

```
  select a,b,c from table A
  select a1,b1,c1 from table A1
  select a2,b2,c2 from table A2
```

Mainly my procedure returns data from these three tables.

But I could not able to understand how to catch them in three separate data set.

Comment: You could either write your own custom data provider that gives the rdlc a DataSet with all three DataTables attached or, see the following link with some ideas using a select statement to pull certain values out of the stored procedure. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can divide three ds and use them like

```
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "STS_rptYarnLedger");

        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("dsSTab1", myDataSet.Tables[0]);
        ReportDataSource datasource1 = new ReportDataSource("dsTab2", myDataSet.Tables[1]);
        ReportDataSource datasource2 = new ReportDataSource("dsTab3", myDataSet.Tables[2]);

        rvYarnStock.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        rvYarnStock.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        rvYarnStock.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource1);
        rvYarnStock.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource1);
```

and to catch the dataset you need to go through a process where for every block (comment out other blocks) you need to execute every block separately.and after getting them in the dataset just execute the full procedure.