# SQL Server insert based on the execution results of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table variable with two columns. The first column is a value that I am trying to populate while the second value is being populated by the execution of a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].userProfiles
   (@userID INT) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sampleTable TABLE (moduleName VARCHAR(20),
                                userProfile int)

    INSERT INTO @sampleTable('userprofile', exec getUserProfile(@userID))

    SELECT *
        FROM @sampleTable
END
```

However, I keep getting this error whenever I try executing the stored procedure:

> Level 15, State 1, Procedure userProfiles, Line 9
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'userprofile'.

Any help will be well appreciated .

Thanks in advance

Comment: `getUserProfile(@userID)` code??

Comment: Didn't find error in this code... I think error in second procedure - exec getUserProfile(@userID)

Comment: you are missing keyword 'values' in insert statement. see my answer.

Comment: @indian this is not a duplicate - i would think a temporary table is different from a table variable... Also the question is a bit different that mine. my question i am using a column with the results from a SP - which is not what the other question had.

Comment: @Edison - Still i would say its a duplicate. People can give you idea of solving your problem not exact answer.

Comment: @indian Isn't that the case with every answer here on SO. At the end of the days it's me aka the person who asked a question who will have to resolve my (his/her) issues.. Awesome Guys and Gals here just help people like me .. just saying...

Comment: @Edison - I believe Praveen's answer should solve your problem. Btw two table variable is not a bad design

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `SP` do have a `select` statement,

see: [SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].userProfiles(
    @userID INT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sampleTable TABLE (
        moduleName VARCHAR(20),
        userProfile int
    )

    DECLARE @stored_proc_table TABLE (
        clmn datatype --similar as result set from getUserProfile
    )

    insert into @stored_proc_table exec getUserProfile(@userID)


    INSERT INTO @sampleTable 
    select 'userprofile', clmn from @stored_proc_table;

    SELECT * FROM @sampleTable
END
```

Comment: two table variables - Would not that be a bad design ?

Comment: @Edison that is the way you can `select` from a stored proc. or change the `sp` to a `table value function`. now you can deal with a one `table variable`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need end your statement with semicolon `;`

[DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188927(v=sql.120).aspx)

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
    EmpID int NOT NULL,
    OldVacationHours int,
    NewVacationHours int,
    ModifiedDate datetime);
```

Comment: nope tht does not work.. :( I am still getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Missing values. Also, consider using out parameter to get value from procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].userProfiles(
    @userID INT) AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sampleTable TABLE(
            moduleName VARCHAR(20),
            userProfile int)

       Create table #valueholder(resultvalue int)
        insert into #valueholder exec getUserProfile(@userID)
        INSERT
          INTO @sampleTable 
select 'userprofile',resultvalue  from #valueholder

        SELECT *
          FROM @sampleTable
    END
```

Also, you cannot make an inline call to procedure. use out parameter.

here is an example about `out` param.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: if i do that I get " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC' " erorr.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, use out parameter to get value from procedure.you cannot call procedure from insert statement. If possible, use function instead of procedure.

Comment: if I remove the modulename from the temp table and the from the insert statement then it works.. it does not work when i pass the modulename. everything else is the same..

Comment: Yes, that works. Because, in that case, you are not treating procedure as paramter. It is executed as standalone statement.

Comment: but that would require me changing the getUserProfile(@userID) procedure right ?  Unfortunately I cannot do that 'cause it is already in production!!!

Comment: @Edison : i updated my answer with a workaround.