# How to do this in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

Here's my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test_SP
        @from int,
        @to int,
        @year int,
        @office varchar(MAX),
        @fund varchar(MAX)
AS             
SELECT        
        AccntTbl.Id,
         AccntTbl.accnt,
          ISNULL(SupplyTbl.Supply, 0) AS Supply,
           AccntTbl.office,
            AccntTbl.exp,                 
        AccntTbl.dateCreated 
FROM         AccntTbl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT idAccnt, 
             SUM(amount) AS Supply
     FROM      SuppyTbl AS SupplyTbl1
     WHERE      (MONTH(dateCreated) BETWEEN @from AND @to) AND
                (YEAR(dateCreated) = @year) AND fund = @fund
     GROUP BY     idAccnt) AS SupplyTbl     
WHERE  YEAR(AccntTbl.dateCreated) = @year AND 
            AccntTbl.office = @office AND
             AccntTbl.fund = @fund 
GROUP BY AccntTbl.Id,
          AccntTbl.accnt,
            AccntTbl.appro,
              Supply.Supply
```

and here to call from VB.NET

```
  conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Test_SP", conn)
    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .Parameters.Add("@from", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
        .Parameters.Add("@to", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
        .Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Int32.Parse(YearLbl.Text)
        .Parameters.Add("@office", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Dashboard.OfficeTxt.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@fund", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FundLbl.Text
    End With
```

How can I retrieve just some of its field in the `TEST_SP` like I just only want `AccntTbl.Accnt` and `ISNULL(SupplyTbl.Supply, 0) as supply`

Here's the example code that I already do

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select AccntTbl.Accnt, ISNULL(SupplyTbl.Supply, 0) as supply from Test_SP", conn)
```

I know it's wrong and it says 'Could not find stored procedure'... lol, glad for any help :)

Comment: You can not. You get all the set or you change the procedure to return only the columns you want.

Comment: @shadow is correct. Another option is pass an additional parameter to either include all or any of the columns you want...

Comment: you could use a function instead of a procedure and then only select the columns you want, additionally you allready check for isnull within the procedure so you do not need to check again

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure) has a few options in the second and third answers using temp tables, which you may want to explore..

Comment: so there is no way the limit the set ? rather than to change the procedure itself ?

Comment: If you don't expect a lot of data to return it's fine to call this procedure and use only the columns you want. But if a lot of data is expected to return then I would change it or -in case that I couldn't because is used from somewhere else-, I would create a lighter version of it with just the columns I want .

Comment: Once you get the results into a dataset, .net lets you edit the datatables in the dataset.  I'm sure you can drop the columns you don't want if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [user defined table valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Test_SP]
(       @from int,
        @to int,
        @year int,
        @office varchar(MAX),
        @fund varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
  SELECT AccntTbl.Id,
         AccntTbl.accnt,
         ISNULL(SupplyTbl.Supply, 0) AS Supply,
         AccntTbl.office,
         AccntTbl.exp,                 
         AccntTbl.dateCreated 
  FROM AccntTbl 
  LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT idAccnt, 
             SUM(amount) AS Supply
     FROM SuppyTbl AS SupplyTbl1
     WHERE MONTH(dateCreated) BETWEEN @from AND @to 
       AND YEAR(dateCreated) = @year 
       AND fund = @fund
     GROUP BY idAccnt) AS SupplyTbl     
  WHERE YEAR(AccntTbl.dateCreated) = @year 
    AND AccntTbl.office = @office 
    AND AccntTbl.fund = @fund 
  GROUP BY AccntTbl.Id,
           AccntTbl.accnt,
           AccntTbl.appro,
           Supply.Supply
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT Accnt, Supply
FROM [dbo].[Test_SP](1, 12, 2015, 'Baltimore', 'aaa');
```

Note that conditions `YEAR(dateCreated) = @year` and `MONTH(dateCreated)` are [nonSARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable#799616) so if there is index on `dateCreated` column query optimizer will skip it.