# Selecting from stored procedure output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to explore the possibility of selecting from a stored procedure.

Something like this

```
SELECT name
FROM exec msdb..sp_help_job
WHERE name = 'SampleJob'
```

I understand [SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure) that a user-defined function or view can be used, but these are not options for me.

Reason being I am not able to run the following SQL statement due to permission limitations on AWS-RDS.

```
SELECT name as Jobs
FROM msdb..sysjobs
```

This leaves me with no choice but to use `msdb..sp_help_job`.

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is this "If job is not created, then run create job script". The reason I need to select from the stored procedure is to see if the job exists.

Appreciate any advice / directions.

Comment: Pass the parameter value ('SampleJob') to your SP and return the result.

Comment: Use a temporary table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without having to create any temp tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create something, but are concerned that it might already exist, then use `try`/`catch` blocks.

```
begin try
    exec dbo.sp_add_job . . .  
end try
begin catch
    print 'Error encountered . . . job probably already exists'
end catch;
```

To be honest, I haven't done this with jobs/job steps.  However, this is one way of re-creating tables, views, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `sp_help_job` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186722%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) this stored procedure has a `@job_name` parameter and a simple return code (0 = success or 1 = failure).

If you set the `@job_name` parameter on your call to `sp_help_job` and get the return code you should be able to test the value of the return code to accomplish what you want.

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = msdb..sp_help_job @job_name = 'MyJobName'

-- @return_value = 1 means the specified @job_name does not exist
IF @return_value = 1 
BEGIN
    --  run create job script
END
```