# Using call procedure results as input table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a stored procedure and I would like to use its output as an input table. Tried something like this but it is not working

```
 SELECT 
      ...
 FROM 
      (SELECT CALL Recommend('input');)
```

How would I be able to use it as my input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure

Comment: @Dresden - Question is tagged with `Mysql`

Comment: I was just mentioning it because of the use of views or a user-defined function over using the output of a stored proc, not really because it was a perfect duplicate of the question being asked.  Sorry, I should have added more to my response.

Comment: It's not possible that way. You can/have to use a temporary table.

Comment: or better yet not a temporary table, but rather a worktable with a session id returned from the first stored proc (OUT param or from result set) and the use of a control table. It is faster and avoids DDL slow downs @Solarflare . It would support concurrency with multiple users doing it at once