# Get count of data returned by a SP in another SP in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SP called GetDailyData in SQL Server 2008 like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDailyData]
   @date datetime
AS
BEGIN
select * from myTable where date >= @date
END
```

I would like to call the stored procedure in another stored procedure and print the number of returned data. I tried this, but did not work:

```
Select COUNT(EXEC GetDailyData @date)
```

How can I perform it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: Also to get a count you can use  [@@ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) after EXEC the SP.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Table of variable to perform it. Here is the code:

```
Declare @T Table (Id int,Name varchar(50))
Insert @T Exec [GetDailyData] @date 
select Count(*) from @T
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EXEC GetDailyData @date
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```