# Getting xml as result from exec stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, for-xml

I'm trying to get the result of an executed stored procedure to be retrieved as a XML of the table the result is shown as originally.

What I'm trying to do is somthing like this.

`exec dbo.StoredProcedure FOR XML RAW, ROOT ('root_name').`

Lets say exec `dbo.StoredProcedure` returns the table in the Stored Procedure,
I want the `FOR XML RAW, ROOT ('root_name')` to return the XML value of that whole result.

How do I achieve this In SQL server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to insert the proc results into a temp table or variable using `INSERT...EXEC` and then select from that table with the desired `FOR XML` query:

```
DECLARE @results AS TABLE(col1 int, col2 int);
INSERT INTO @results EXEC dbo.StoredProcedure;
SELECT col1, col2
FROM @results
FOR XML RAW, ROOT ('root_name');
```

Comment: Just a little side question here, is there anyway to export that xml result to an xml file in the disk with an sql query?

Comment: @John, although you could do that with SQLCLR or xp_cmdshell ugliness, I suggest you don't go there. It's trivial save the XML with a client app or script, like Powershell.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the info, I will definitely look into my options.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure) question, you should not select from the stored procedure. Also if you dig into that question, you will find a link to an interesting [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) describing options you have with stored procedures.

If I were you I would either return an XML with an output parameter, or insert-exec into a table and then query it with for xml.