# How to call a stored procedure that has two OUTPUT parameters from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I wasn't able to find anything that worked for me.

I have a stored procedure that has two OUTPUT parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.xxx
    .
    .
    .
    @param1 INT OUTPUT,
    @param2 INT OUTPUT 
AS
```

and I want to call it from another stored procedure.

I know how to do it when there is one OUTPUT parameter, but I don't know how to call it so I also get the value of the second one. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure#comment1344628_1492446 this is a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Sample procedure with two output parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SumAndMultiply
(
    @In int,
    @OutSum int output,
    @OutMultiply int output
)
AS

    SELECT  @OutSum = @In + @In,
            @OutMultiply = @In * @In

GO
```

Sample procedure that executes the first one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE executeSumAndMultiply
(
    @In int
)
AS

DECLARE @Out1 int, 
        @Out2 int

EXEC SumAndMultiply @In = @In, @OutSum = @Out1 OUTPUT, @OutMultiply = @Out2 OUTPUT

SELECT @Out1 As Out1, @Out2 As Out2

GO
```

Execute the second procedure:

```
EXEC executeSumAndMultiply 3
```

Results:

```
Out1    Out2
6        9
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/HEWXG64237)

Comment: That did it, thank you very much for the fast response! (I have to wait 4 more minutes to accept your post as the answer)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create procedure first_proc(@p1 int, @p2 int out, @p3 int out)
> as
>     set @p2 = 1;
>     set @p3 = 10;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create procedure second_proc
> as
>     declare @f1 int;
>     declare @f2 int;
>
>     exec dbo.first_proc 10, @f1 out, @f2 out;
>
>     select 'Returned values:' t, @f1, @f2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> exec dbo.second_proc;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> t                | (No column name) | (No column name)
> :--------------- | ---------------: | ---------------:
> Returned values: |                1 |               10
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed8e4ed9e71f0656ffe96d7bcc418017)*

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the below Approach, i Just given a sample example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_NestedSP
    @CurrentDate DATETIME OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE()
END
GO
--Nested SP which accepts OUTPUT parameter
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MainSP
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
    EXEC [usp_NestedSP] @CurrentDate OUTPUT
    SELECT @CurrentDate AS 'ResultFromNestedSP'

END
GO

EXEc usp_MainSP
```