# How to retrieve specified columns instead of all from stored procedure resutls?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

```
sp_describe_first_result_set  @tsql=N'%s'
```

returns a lot of info. But I only want `name` and `system_type_name`.

Is it possible to specify the columns in the returned results?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: If there is any chance to use an *inline table valued function* instead, you should do this. This is faster, more reusable and much easier to consume.

Comment: What do you mean by using inline tvf, could you elaberate ? despite the sql part, I am quite familiar with sql server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: I did more search, I guess the answer is not without lot of effort. Closing thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first dump all columns in a temp table and select only the necessary columns from that.

```
create table #1 (name varchar(50), system_type_name varchar(50), col3 int, col4 int)
 insert into #1 (name, system_type_name, col3, col4)
        exec dbo.sp_describe_first_result_set
      select name, system_type_name from #1
  drop table #1
```

Comment: I think your answer will be more useful if you add an example.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks, but `sp_describe_first_result_set` returns 30+ columns... the table definition is very long.

Comment: @Ben, yes it will require a bit of typing for all of the source column names. It's just a one-time task.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @Steef's answer, below is the table definition matching the result set as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @results TABLE(
      is_hidden bit NOT NULL
    , column_ordinal int NOT NULL   
    , name sysname NULL
    , is_nullable bit NOT NULL
    , system_type_id int NOT NULL
    , system_type_name sysname NULL
    , max_length smallint NOT NULL
    , precision tinyint NOT NULL
    , scale tinyint NOT NULL    
    , collation_name sysname NULL
    , user_type_id int NULL
    , user_type_database sysname NULL
    , user_type_schema sysname NULL
    , user_type_name sysname NULL
    , assembly_qualified_type_name nvarchar(4000) NULL
    , xml_collection_id int NULL
    , xml_collection_database sysname NULL
    , xml_collection_schema sysname NULL
    , xml_collection_name sysname NULL
    , is_xml_document bit NOT NULL
    , is_case_sensitive bit NOT NULL
    , is_fixed_length_clr_type bit NOT NULL
    , source_server sysname NULL
    , source_database sysname NULL
    , source_schema sysname NULL
    , source_table sysname NULL 
    , source_column sysname NULL
    , is_identity_column bit  NULL
    , is_part_of_unique_key bit NULL
    , is_updateable bit  NULL
    , is_computed_column bit  NULL
    , is_sparse_column_set bit  NULL
    , ordinal_in_order_by_list smallint NULL
    , order_by_is_descending smallint NULL
    , order_by_list_length smallint NULL
    , tds_type_id int NOT NULL
    , tds_length int NOT NULL
    , tds_collation_id int NULL
    , tds_collation_sort_id tinyint NULL
);
```

Comment: thanks sir. I am trying to get the desc. of an arbitrary query, since I always have to create sth. I am turing to creating tempview>query form information_schema>teardown tempview, which is I was doing in pgsql.