# How to call Stored Procedure in Views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view, sql-function

My stored procedure do not have parameters. Running it as below:-

```
EXEC sp_Email_spd_CasualNotification
```

Returns a table:-

```
DeptChangeID| oldDeptID |DeptID | JobID |EmpID
33419       | NULL      | 679   | 3742  |16575
42392       | NULL      | 783   | 4742  |100000378
```

I want to view this table in View. I just can't find a way.
What I meant was

```
CREATE View [dbo].[vw_EmploymentLatest] as  
Select * from (EXEC sp_Email_spd_CasualNotification)
```

This is not possible.

My stored procedure simplified as below:-

```
declare @empTable table (employeeID int)
declare @selectedDeptChangeIDTable table (deptChangeID int)
declare @rowCount int
declare @rowNum int
declare @selectedDeptChangeID int
declare @empID int

Insert into @empTable (employeeID)
SELECT DISTINCT
E.Employee_ID
FROM Employee E
'
'

WHILE exists (select * from @empTable)
BEGIN    
SELECT @empID = (select top 1 employeeID from @empTable order by employeeID asc)

'
'

WHILE @rowNum <= @rowCount
BEGIN
declare @p1 int
declare @p2 int
'
'
'
'
DELETE @empTable WHERE employeeID = @empID 
END

Select * from Employment Where DeptChangeID in (Select deptChangeID from @selectedDeptChangeIDTable)
```

Comment: **DO NOT EVER** use [`sp_`](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) prefix, it's reserved for System Stored Procodures by MS.

Comment: _I want to view this table in View_ What does this mean?

Comment: To add to the comment from @Sam : [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). How do you expect us to convert your (unparametrised) Stored Procedure into a View without the SP's DDL? We can't see your SQL, nor do we have a crystal ball. Please help us help you.

Comment: You can't "`SELECT`" from a Stored procedure, no; you execute it. If you need to have replicate the result set from an Stored Procedure into a view, then you need to use the `SELECT` statement inside your SP.

Comment: I did Select statement at the end of my sp. That is why i'm getting that result table. How do I use this result table as a reference table (example temporary table, or virtual table (Views)?

Comment: It's not possible to call an stored procedure within a view. An alternative could be to convert your stored procedure into a table-valued function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - SELECT FROM stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures are not intended to be used within views (or functions). You'll have to write your query on the view or alternatively on a function.

Lets suppose this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables
GO

EXEC dbo.Test
```

It can be converted into a table-valued function like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
  SELECT * FROM sys.tables
)
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test()
```

Now this can be used within a view, if you want to.

That was the simpler syntax (in-line function) but for any complex stored procedure you will need to convert it into a multi-statement table-valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test
RETURNS @Test TABLE (object_id int, name varchar(100)) 
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Test (object_id, name)
         SELECT object_id, name FROM sys.tables
END
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test()
```

Looking at the code you have provided, your function would be something like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Email_spd_CasualNotification
RETURNS @CasualNotification TABLE (DeptChangeID int, oldDeptID int, DeptID int, JobID int, EmpID int) 
AS
BEGIN
  declare @empTable table (employeeID int)
  declare @selectedDeptChangeIDTable table (deptChangeID int)
  declare @rowCount int
  declare @rowNum int
  declare @selectedDeptChangeID int
  declare @empID int

  Insert into @empTable (employeeID)
         SELECT DISTINCT
         E.Employee_ID
         FROM Employee E
         '
         '

  WHILE exists (select * from @empTable)
  BEGIN    
    SELECT @empID = (select top 1 employeeID from @empTable order by employeeID asc)

    '
    '

    WHILE @rowNum <= @rowCount
    BEGIN
      declare @p1 int
      declare @p2 int
      '
      '
      '
      '
      DELETE @empTable WHERE employeeID = @empID 
    END
  END  

  insert into @CasualNotification(DeptChangeID, oldDeptID, DeptID, JobID, EmpID)
         Select DeptChangeID, oldDeptID, DeptID, JobID, EmpID 
         from Employment 
         Where DeptChangeID in (Select deptChangeID from @selectedDeptChangeIDTable)
END
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for you answer. Please refer my updated question. I tried inserting my procedure 'declare @empTable table .. ' . However it's red on 'declared' . Can we declare variable inside the RETURN ()?

Comment: Hi Safwan, I have provided two syntaxes for table-valued functions. If you want to declare variables and use multiple instructions, you have to use the second syntax : multi-statement table-valued functions. That syntax doesn't have a RETURN section.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I implemented the same thing and works charm. You're a genius!!

Comment: @SafwanMasarik I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure should contain a `SELECT` statement on the table(s) you want to query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Then you call your procedure:

```
EXEC sp_Email_spd_CasualNotification
```

If your procedure is not doing any alterations to the tables why not consider using a `FUNCTION`?

Note: The `sp_` prefix is reserved for System Stored Procedures, so I would change the name.

Comment: Since his `SP` returns a table, sure he `SELECT FROM TABLE(s)`.

Comment: Yes I did Select in the SP. How do you execute in Views. And how do I execute this SP in Function given that I don't pass any parameter?

Comment: You can't execute stored procedure within views or functions. Stored Procedure are not intended for that use. You'll have to write a proper view or a proper function, with all the code to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: Usually what I do in SQL server management studio is: New Query (CTRL +N), then type : exec STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME. If you just need a view you have to create a view which is totally different from a Function or a StoredProcedure

Comment: If you need an example of a view here is a sample that queries 2 tables using join http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd2a3b/1

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
    SELECT * FROM sys.tables
GO

EXEC dbo.Test
```

upd: for use in view (why? may by table/inline function?)

add linked server (local)

```
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LinkedServer', @srvproduct = N'sqlserver', @provider = N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc = N'LinkedServer.domain';
```

and try

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw
AS
SELECT * 
FROM       OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'EXEC [YOURDB].dbo.Test') AS a
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.vw
```

Comment: I love this answer, almost similar to my research. However can you explain the Add linked server (local) part and Openquery part. I don't understand how it works?