# Doing a count over a subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

We have an application which allows users to define queries. We would like to do a count over any possible subquery

e.g.

Configured SQL - Which works fine:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData
EXEC [StoredPRoc]
Select * from TempSurpacData
```

We then attempt a count over this query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData
    EXEC [StoredPRoc]
    Select * from TempSurpacData
) tbl
```

This unfortunately fails ...

Answer (score 0):

The DROP TABLE and EXEC statements should be outside the select statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData
EXEC [StoredPRoc]
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    Select * from TempSurpacData
) tbl
```

Or

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData
EXEC [StoredPRoc]
Select count(*) from TempSurpacData
```

If you really can't do it this way you can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/how-to-select-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: The first query I am not in control of this is entered by a user via textbox in our app. So we basically want to do a count over any query entered by a user we do make sure the user query returns rows prior to saving it.

Answer (score 0):

You have given very little info.

what  `[StoredPRoc]` does ? Like `[StoredPRoc]` also return some result and `Select * from TempSurpacData` also return some result then you need count of which resultset.

> we do make sure the user query returns rows prior to saving it.

when you can do this then surely you can find row count in same place, just we don't know what code is use there.

> The first query I am not in control of this is entered by a user via
> textbox in our app

What do you mean by this ? Does user enter only `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData` or your complete example.

This is just layman example.

```
declare @i varchar(500)='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempData
EXEC [StoredPRoc]
Select * from TempSurpacData'

exec(@i)
Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

Suppose in my exampe both `EXEC [StoredPRoc]` and `Select * from TempSurpacData` return rows then

```
Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

will give number of rows return by `Select * from TempSurpacData`